# Mercurial Newbie confused

Tags: mercurial

I am familiar with TFS and Vault, but having just started using Mercurial I seem to be getting into a bit of a mess.

Heres what I (think) I've done:

-Created a central repository on bitbucket.org

-On my desktop PC, cloned repository from bitbucket, added files, commit them, push them to bitbucket

-On my laptop, cloned repository from bitbucket, pulled files, added more files, commit them, push them to bitbucket

I've continued to add, edit etc on the different computers.

Now I've noticed that some files from each computer are not in the bitbucket repository, and therefore only in the local repository.  No amount of pulling and pushing seems to get it into the bitbucket repository.

What is the most likely thing I've done wrong?
Is there a way to 'force' by changes up to the bitbucket repository?

Comment: Show `hg out` and `hg st` results

Comment: Is the repository public on bitbucket? If it is, could you zip up your local clone and make it available somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did they get into your local repository?  I suspect not, i.e. they were new files that were not added to the commit.  Use `hg add` to add them to the changeset before committing or whatever the equivalent is for whatever mercurial interface you're using.

*Edit:*

Here's the help from Mercurial:

```
C:\Users\Bert>hg add --help
hg add [OPTION]... [FILE]...

add the specified files on the next commit

    Schedule files to be version controlled and added to the repository.

    The files will be added to the repository at the next commit. To undo an
    add before that, see "hg forget".

    If no names are given, add all files to the repository.
...
```

See ***Mercurial: The Definitive Guide*** (a.k.a. the hg "red book") for more info:

http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/mercurial-in-daily-use.html

> **Telling Mercurial which files to track**
>
> Mercurial does not work with files in your repository unless you tell it to manage them. The hg status command will tell you which files Mercurial doesn't know about; it uses a “?” to display such files.
>
> To tell Mercurial to track a file, use the `hg add` command. Once you have added a file, the entry in the output of hg status for that file changes from “?” to “A”.

```
$ hg init add-example
$ cd add-example
$ echo a > myfile.txt
$ hg status
? myfile.txt
$ hg add myfile.txt
$ hg status
A myfile.txt
$ hg commit -m 'Added one file'
$ hg status

use "hg -v help add" to show global options
```

Comment: "Use hg add to add them to the changeset" --- it is a little incorrect to say this.

Comment: @zerkms - please enlighten me

Comment: even if file was added it doesn't mean that it will be commited to the changeset, since `hg ci` can accept a list of files to commit (or exclude). Indeed it is not important thing to discuss but I'm sure it will be good for newbie to know such things.

Comment: I think there must be a bug in the software I'm using:  VisualHG with Visual Studio2010.   When I drop to a command line it all seems to work properly.